Extending Logical Volume Size Beyond 2TB in CentOS 7
I need to extend the size of the logical volumes in a CentOS 7 system and noticed that the current partition table cannot handle the updated disk size, which is around 5TB:
Disk /dev/sda: 5497.6 GB, 5497558138880 bytes, 10737418240 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000bc7c4

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048     2099199     1048576   83  Linux
/dev/sda2         2099200  2147483647  1072692224   8e  Linux LVM

I know that I have to use parted along with GPT but couldn't find a guideline on how to first change the partition table and then expand the volumes accordingly.
Could you please help me with this?

This is the issue: Disk label type: dos. Drives over 2TB must be gpt partitioned. MBR(msdos) was designed back in the early 1980's when MB was large, so they set max to the unheard of size of 2TB which would never be used on PCs.  Conversion normally deletes all data, so make good backups, convert drive to gpt & reinstall.  Converting to or from GPT - must have good backups.
http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/mbr2gpt.html

Do you mean that conversion also deletes the root filesystem as well?

You are totally changing the drive. If partitions, not LVM, the gdisk conversion may (only may) keep data, but would at minimum require reinstall of grub. And gpt drives need either an ESP - efi system partition for UEFI boot (systems since 2012) or a bios_grub for BIOS boot for older systems or those installed in very old BIOS boot mode. Otherwise grub cannot install. But since using LVM, you must have good backups anyway & reinstall should be quick.

Before working with the actual machine, I created another VM which has the same partition table with the actual one. The procedure I followed: STEP #1: Convert partition table to GPT via gdisk. STEP #2: Re-install GRUB via grub2-install. STEP #3: Create a new physical volume via pvcreate. STEP #4: Apply the LVM resize instructions. After that, I was able to observe that the VM boots and LVM has been resized.

Based on @oldfred's guidance and technical articles 1 and 2, I applied the following procedure:

Step 1: Convert partition table to GPT via gdisk
Step 2: Create one BIOS boot partition (partition type code = ef02)
Step 3: Create one Linux LVM partition (partition type code = 8e00)
Step 4: Reload the partition table with partprobe and re-install GRUB
with grub2-install
Step 5: Create new physical volume with pvcreate
Step 6: Extend the volume group with vgextend
Step 7: Extend the respective logical volume group with lvextend
Step 8: Increase the size of the mounted XFS filesystem with xfs_growfs

